# Docker - WORKDIR issue on alpine image (Multi-Stages build)

Tags: docker, docker-entrypoint, workdir

I have this second stage for my Dockerfile:

```
############################################ MULTI STAGE BUILD PART 2 ##############################################

# Start from alpine image
FROM alpine

# Creating work directory
WORKDIR /service

# Copy the certificats and executable into new Docker image
COPY --from=builder /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt /etc/ssl/certs/
COPY --from=builder /service/main /service/
COPY --from=builder /service/.credentials /service/.credentials/

# Expose port
EXPOSE ${GRPC_PORT}
EXPOSE ${REST_PORT}

## Get required ARGs and put them into ENVs variables
ARG ENVIRONMENT
ARG NAMESPACE
ARG GRPC_PORT
ARG REST_PORT
ENV _ENVIRONMENT=${ENVIRONMENT}
ENV _NAMESPACE=${NAMESPACE}
ENV _GRPC_PORT=${GRPC_PORT}
ENV _REST_PORT=${REST_PORT}

### HERE YOU CAN TEST WITH ANY OF THE FOLLOWING ENTRYPOINT

# The One I need
ENTRYPOINT /main "ENVIRONMENT=${_ENVIRONMENT}" "NAMESPACE=${_NAMESPACE}" "GRPC_PORT=${_GRPC_PORT}" "REST_PORT=${_REST_PORT}"

# This one isn't able to resolve ENVs variables, but I use it as an example for my ISSUE
ENTRYPOINT [ "/main" ]
```

> As you can see, the WORKDIR is set to be /service

However, if you run the image with the first entrypoint, you get:

`/bin/sh: /main: not found`

And if you run with the second entrypoint, you get:

`docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:346: starting container process caused "exec: \"/main\": stat /main: no such file or directory": unknown.`

**Note:** Another interesting point is the *COPY --from=builder ...* where I need to set the dest as `/service/` otherwise my file gets copied in the `/` directory

---

**According to the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#workdir):**

> The WORKDIR instruction sets the working directory for any RUN, CMD,
>   ENTRYPOINT, COPY and ADD instructions that follow it in the
>   Dockerfile.

---

Any idea? Is it really relating to me or Docker/alpine?

Comment: your entrypoint needs to be `./main` not `/main`. `./main` points to /service/main.

Comment: Ok I am trying now, but then why `main` doesn't work neither?

Comment: plain jane `main` would look for somthin in your $PATH

Comment: Ok you were right... I lost 2h and a half to figure this `.` out.. Please write an answer so I can accept it for you

Comment: dude it happens. the amount I time my life has been devoted to a single missing character is what to high.

Answer added. (you can also upvote comments :))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Entrypoint` needs to be ./main.

`/main` is an absolute path would refer to a main that was on your root.

Since you are in `/service` you will need a relative path. You want `./main`, which points to `/service/main`.

Comment: Thanks, small mistake on my end then!